# Development team has reached maximum number of registered iPhone devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

Whenever I try to build an iOS app to my iPhone device I get the following error:

> Your development team has reached the maximum number of registered iPhone devices.

I've previously had a Developer Program Membership that is now expired that I used to build apps on my old iPhone.

How can I delete that old iPhone from my list of devices? The [Apple Developer support page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html) says
I should go to `Certificates, IDs & Profiles` at https://developer.apple.com/account/ but I can't find that menu.[image]

Comment: You can normally update the list of devices once per year, but as you no longer have a paid membership, this option is not available. Either renew your membership or use a different Apple id

Comment: you need *not to add* the old devices to the list of devices during the renewal, and that procedure technically deletes them; after the renewal has done, and you have forgot not to add the devices again, you'll need to wait until the next renewal at that account.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Contacted the Apple Developer Program Support who solved it by deleting the old devices associated to the old membership.

Comment: the rep I talked to said that the devices on my old (now 2+ year expired) apple Developer paid account were inactive and shouldn't affect my use of the "Xcode program" to which I'm trying to add my iPad and getting this too many devices error. How can I convince them to delete the devices from the old membership when they think its not going to affect anything?

Comment: Infortunately it did not work for me. I got a reply that in order to remove the devices I should renew my subscription.

Comment: this is the correct way to solve this issue other than paying apple, I was told it could take 12-24 hours for the change to take effect.

Comment: I did this today and although I had to wait on hold on the phone for 20 minutes the rep figured out the right thing to do.

Comment: I can confirm that after emailing Apple regarding this issue (3+ devices on previous paid account, no longer paid) they were able to clear my devices. Took about <1hr for them to respond.

Comment: I contacted Apple last week to so if they could do this for my currently free (previously paid) membership, see the response:

"In your message, you have requested for device list reset. Unfortunately, we are unable to process this request.

For free members, using Xcode to test apps on an iOS Device is intended for personal use, so there are limits on the number of assets you can register at one time. Please allow the current registered device registrations to expire before proceeding to add new devices."

The solution is to buy a new membership to access the device registrations.

Comment: I can confirm that calling their developer support and asking them to clear old devices on an expired account works. I reached them via Apple Developer > Contact Us > Membership and Account > Developer Team Management. Took just under 10mins total.

Answer (score 44):

I believe this is a problem with paid developer accounts that have expired and become free developer accounts.  Technically free accounts are limited to 3 devices.  If you have a previous paid account that had more than 3, I bet Apple didn't clear out those devices, which means you are over your limit of devices.  Other are experiencing the issue [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66893).

I think your best move would be to sign up for a new, free account, or pay to restore your access to the full 100 device limit for a paid individual account.

Comment: At least Apple could leave us an option to choose which three devices we want to use after Membership has expired. Rather than it just hides menu items and tell us to renew membership. I had to google like 3hours until I figured out this. This is not a feature IMO, this is a bug :)

Comment: Technically, for Apple it's a feature to drive adoption of paid developer accounts.  It's a bug for consumers who expected a transition from paid to free to work retain full funcitonality.

Answer (score 1):

This is a paid developer account expired issue. You can do multiple tricks to resolve this issue for small instance --

1. Change `Bundle Identifier` (it works sometimes)
2. Add a different Apple Developer account to build(no need to pay, the free one work for up to 3 devices)

To check your Account status - [developer account](https://developer.apple.com/account)